# stub_command with node attribute variables

Tags: chef-infra, chefspec

I've google around, it appears this can be done, but I'm just doing it wrong apparently.

So I'm trying to run this snippet of `powershell_script`:

```
powershell_script 'Unzip' do
  code <<-EOH
  Expand-Archive -Path 'E:\\apache-tomee-1.7.4-plus.zip' -DestinationPath "E:\\#{node['COOKBOOK']['Product']}-#{node['COOKBOOK']['Region']}-" + count.to_s.rjust(2, "0")"
  EOH
  guard_interpreter :powershell_script
  not_if "Test-Path -Path E:\\#{node['COOKBOOK']['Product']}-#{node['COOKBOOK']['Region']}-01"
end
```

Now those node attributes are set in attributes default.rb

```
default['COOKBOOK']['Product'] = 'product'
default['COOKBOOK']['Region'] = 'region'
```

I'm having a problem getting from there to what's supposed to be in the spec file.

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe 'COOKBOOK::default' do
  context 'when all attributes are default, on Windows 2012R2' do
    let(:chef_run) do
      # for a complete list of available platforms and versions see:
      # https://github.com/customink/fauxhai/blob/master/PLATFORMS.md
      runner = ChefSpec::ServerRunner.new(platform: 'windows', version: '2012R2')
      runner.converge(described_recipe)
    end
    it 'converges successfully' do
      stub_command('Test-Path -Path E:\\#{node['COOKBOOK']['Product']}-#{node['COOKBOOK']['Region']}-01').and_return(true)
      expect { chef_run }.to_not raise_error
    end
  end
end
```

Can anyone give me a hand?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you getting an error? What exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

First, you have an issue with the `stub_command` line. You have the line surrounded with single quotes so those interpolations for attributes aren't going to work, so surround the thing in double quotes:

```
stub_command("Test-Path -Path E:\\#{node['COOKBOOK']['Product']}-#{node['COOKBOOK']['Region']}-01").and_return(true)
```

Now you will get this error:

```
 NameError:
   undefined local variable or method `node' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::ExampleSoDefault::WhenAllAttributesAreDefaultOnWindows2012R2:0x0000000004066720>
```

Your node attributes aren't available in your rspec tests. In additon, `rspec` recognizes your `not_if` with attributes already replaced, like this:

```
not_if "Test-Path -Path E:\\product-region-01"
```

So you need to stub that command, like follows:

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe 'example-so::default' do
  context 'when all attributes are default, on Windows 2012R2' do
    let(:chef_run) do
      # for a complete list of available platforms and versions see:
      # https://github.com/customink/fauxhai/blob/master/PLATFORMS.md
      runner = ChefSpec::ServerRunner.new(platform: 'windows', version: '2012R2')
      runner.converge(described_recipe)
    end
    it 'converges successfully' do
      stub_command('Test-Path -Path E:\\product-region-01').and_return(true)
      expect { chef_run }.to_not raise_error
    end
  end
end
```

If you need to test for multiple different attribute settings you can [set attributes](https://github.com/chefspec/chefspec#setting-node-attributes) appropriately and run tests for each set of conditions.